# Error when running stored procedure : maximum number of object durations exceeded seems when variable not pass it works

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm newbie in stored procedures and I create a stored procedure, but when I run it by user input, I get an error; but when get value to variable `daynumber`, it is working.

Suggetions from SQL Developer are:

> *Cause:    This typically happens if there is infinite recursion in the PL/SQLfunction that is being executed.
>
> *Action:   User should alter the recursion condition in order to prevent infinite recursion.

How can I solve it?

```
create or replace procedure P_SiteNumber_Range_D(Sitenum NUMBER) is
 daynumber number;
begin
 p_sitenumber_range_d(Sitenum => daynumber);
  -- daynumber := 2;
 for l in (select PROVINCE from v_sitenumber_D_province_range)
   loop
     update PM4h_db.IND_D_3102
   set IND_D_3102_029 =
       (select countsite from some table where l1.province=province );
   end loop;
end P_SiteNumber_Range_D;
```

Run procedure as :

```
DECLARE
  SITENUM NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SITENUM := 3;

  P_SITENUMBER_RANGE_D(
    SITENUM => SITENUM
  );
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure doesn't make much sense (at least, to me).

- you are passing `sitenum` and never do anything with it; should it be used in `where` clause in cursor `for` loop and/or `update` statement?
- this is a procedure, and then - in line #4 of your original code - you are calling itself (which then calls itself which calls itself etc., until Oracle stops it and returns an error)

  - the most obvious "solution" is to remove that statement:

    ```
    p_sitenumber_range_d(Sitenum => daynumber);
    ```

    but that probably won't be all, because of my first objection

Furthermore, maybe you don't need the loop at all, as the whole code can be rewritten as

```
create or replace procedure p_sitenumber_range_d (par_sitenum in number)
is
begin
  update pm4h_db.ind_d_3102 set
    ind_d_3102_029 = (select countsite
                      from some_table
                      where province = (select province
                                        from v_sitenumber_d_province_range
                                        where sitenum = par_sitenum
                                       )
                     );
end;
```

It might, or might not work - there's a possibility of `TOO_MANY_ROWS` if `select` returns more than a single value. I don't know, as I don't have your tables, so - that might need to be fixed.

If you insist on the loop, then consider such a code:

```
create or replace procedure p_sitenumber_range_d (par_sitenum in number)
is
begin
  for cur_r in (select province
                from v_sitenumber_d_province_range
                where sitenum = par_sitenum
               )
  loop
    update pm4h_db.ind_d_3102 set
      ind_d_3102_029 = (select countsite 
                        from some_table
                        where province = cur_r.province
                       );
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you've built in a recursion?
The first thing you do during the procedure is to call up the procedure itself!

Comment: I don't aware about them can you guide me please, how can i pass varible of user to my varible